# enters an infinite loop when catching exception

Tags: java, exception

```
int option;
    while(true) {
        try {
            option = sc.nextInt();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            continue;
        }
        if(option != 1 && option !=2) {
            System.out.println("Please choose one of the above options!");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
```

so why if I input a string the code enters an infinite loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you catch you call `continue` and the loops goes straight to the next iteration.

**EDIT**: silly me, you need to call `hasNextInt()` before any call to `nextInt()`. You probably exhausted the input and thus the same exception gets thrown over and over.

Note that `hasNextInt()` will block if you are using the input stream. That will basically simulate a program that "waits" for user input.

Comment: OK ,,  and in the next iteration the code should ask me for input again but it doesn't ,, it automatically jump to the "catch" block and reprinting the error message over and over again !!

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't pause in the middle of the loop to re-scan the next User input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to make the user choose option 1 or option 2:

Your code says if their choice isn't both 1 and 2, then continue. It should say if their choice isn't 1 or 2, then continue, which would be coded like this:

```
if(option != 1 && option != 2) {
    System.out.println("Please choose one of the options");
    continue;
}
```

By the way, using continue and break is bad coding. Instead, use a while loop with the if condition in it.

**EDIT:**

Here is the correct `while` loop:

```
try {
    option = sc.nextInt();
    while(option != 1 && option != 2)
        System.out.println("Please choose one of the options");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT #2:**

You're also trying to continue code after catching a possible exception. You should put that code in a `finally {}` block if you want to ensure it gets run, regardless of the exception. However, in this case it is not needed. Usually the `finally{}` block is used to I/O streams.

Comment: you are right, I want the user to choose 1 or 2 but the "or" isn't correct , because if it's || and for example  option=1 so then (option!=2) => true , and by that the code enters the "if" block

Comment: if option==1, then the condition never gets to (option==2). However, if option==2, it first checks and finds that (option!=1), then checks and finds (option==2) (as stated by the ||). This gives the user the ability to only enter in 1 or 2, or it reiterates through the while loop. Thus, the || is correct, not &&

Comment: EDIT: after thinking about it you are correct: it should be && and not ||. My apologies.